# Pragma and Interrupt Vector Table : TI MSP430

Tags: c, embedded, pragma, msp430

My program contains few global variables , whose values are set during the interrupt service routine (USCI_A0_ISR()) execution.

Once the execution of USCI_A0_ISR() is done , will the global variables hold the value assigned or will be set back to void/0.????

```
//Global variables
int ptr = 0;
char rxBuffer[16]; 
int flag = -1;
int check[2];

void __set_flag(void)
{

    if (strcmp(rxBuffer,"OK") == 0) flag = 0; 
    else if (strcmp(rxBuffer,"CONNECT") == 0) flag = 1;
    else if (strcmp(rxBuffer,"NO CARRIER") == 0) flag = 3;
    else if (strcmp(rxBuffer,"ERROR") == 0) flag = 4;

}

void __GSM_client(void)
{
    while (flag == -1);
    if (flag == 0) check[0] = buflen(rxBuffer);
}

void main(void)
{
    __Buffer_init();
    __low_level_init();         //WDT 
    __UART0_init();                 //UART 

    __bis_SR_register(GIE);       //interrupts enabled
    __delay_cycles(1000);           // wait till UART intial

    __GSM_client();

    __no_operation();             // For debugger
}

#pragma vector=USCI_A0_VECTOR
__interrupt void USCI_A0_ISR(void)
{
    char byte;
    while (!(UCA0IFG&UCTXIFG));             
    byte=  UCA0RXBUF;
    UCA0TXBUF = byte;
    if (byte == '\r') { 
        //push_char(byte);
        ptr = 0;
        __set_flag();
        //__Buffer_init();              
    }
    else{                       
        push_char(byte);
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet of what I am doing. I am setting the `"flag"` based on the response obtained . When I see the register view in Code Composer Studio , the `"flag"` value is set correctly , but if try using the value of `"flag"` elsewhere the value of `"flag "` is not reflected.

Any pointers over concepts of the interrupt service routine or when loopholes in my coding method appreciated
Thanks in Advance
***AK***

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but is it necessary to name all your functions as `__*`? Identifiers beginning with `__` are typically reserved for use by the platform libraries.

Comment: most of them intrinsic functions , except for __GSM_client() . Well thanks for bring that point to my notice

Comment: `main` has no loop.  Is that intentional?  If you don't generate the interupt in the first 1000 cycles of operation, you won't see it. (That's only 40 microsec for a 25Mhz processor).

Comment: @ AShelly , I have intentionally skipped `main()`, because it didn had much to   do with. And about `__delay_cycles();` I have later written my own delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the interrupt, you are directly or indirectly changing several global variables, e.g. ptr, flag, and I'm assuming rxBuffer[?].  They are not declared "volatile" so their value *may or may not change* when you return from the interrupt.  This is a bug because the behavior can change based on where in the execution of the code the interrupt occurs and what the level of optimization is.  As a rule of thumb, any variable modified by an interrupt routine should always be declared volatile.

Comment: `volatile int ptr = 0;
   char rxBuffer[16]; 
   volatile int flag = -1;` 
well this doesn't seem to do any good.

Comment: @abhay - benpro also mentioned `rxbuffer`, we both think it's likely that it's also shared between the ISR & the background loop, hence it should also be volatile.  Try making it volatile & if it doesn't work, you might want to step through the assembly (or post it here)

Comment: @abhay also you're not pushing any kind of terminating character into the buffer.  How does buflen() know when to stop counting?  Pls post the source.  Presumably it works by looking for a NULL, and it's working the first time because rxbuffer is probably bss-zero-initialized before main(), but after the first iteration, a smaller command in rxbuffer will cause buflen() to return a greater than correct value.  Right now as a one-shot I guess it's OK but it's very (and unnecessarily) fragile.

Comment: @Dan I tried making rxBuffer[] volatile , but strmcmp() complains  i.e `strcmp(rxBuffer,"OK")`
 _argument of type "volatile char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char "_
Yup you got me right at `buflen()` i check for `NULL`

Comment: @Dan looks like i cant use `strmcp()` b'coz `int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );` use a const parameter

Comment: @Dan making `ruBuffer` wasn't help either . Well since the code is pretty big I am not able to post it here

Comment: @benpro and Dan thanks for feedback , with some cool head i got to the bones and things worked out

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that making the shared variables volatile isn't working then I'd suspect you have redefined a global variable as a local variable somewhere. Check the address of the flag variable when you are debugging and make sure it is the same in __set_flag() and outwith the interrupt, where you think it has not been updated.

I also think that the polling loop in your ISR is poor code and you should find a better way to wait for the transmitter to be ready for the next character.

Comment: thanks for the feedback . Well about the Polling loop , the code skeleton has been borrowed from TI website where sample code snippets are available.

Comment: @Abhay: So what was the final solution? Remember, you can post your own answer to your own question if you think the solution you found or the methods you used would be useful to other people.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all the feedback i got from the members. Well the idea of declaring all the ***"variables volatile"*** did the trick . `strcmp()` uses  const var* so i couldn't use it . I had to write my own custom string compare function. All this minor things solved my problems.

Comment: You could have just cast the volatile buffer to the correct type and used the strcmp function.

Comment: If `volatile` was the right answer, why not choose @benpro's answer as the correct one??